# Delphi 7 crashes after installing Delphi XE (BPL mixed paths)

Tags: delphi

After installing Delphi XE, my good-old Delphi 7 started to crash more often. Today, I have discovered that one of my BPLs was still loaded by D7 even if I deleted it from "c:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Projects\Bpl".
After I have searched the entire disk I have discovered a copy of that BPL in "c:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\8.0\Bpl".

My question is: why is Delphi 7 looking in "c:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\8.0\Bpl"?
How can I convince it to look only in "c:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Projects\Bpl" ?

Comment: I think one of those paths in your second paragraph was supposed to mention Delphi XE, no?

Comment: IIRC there are project-local settings for this as well as the global ones. Check both. Also, IIRC BPLs are DLLs with some Delphi-magic included, so it's possible that the (global) DLL search path (`PATH` variable among others) interferes.

Comment: Welcome to self-inflicted DLL/BPL hell.  DLLs and BPLs don't load from one folder only, they load from wherever they are found, by name, in the path.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Delphi XE probably augments the PATH environment variable to include the Delphi XE Bpl folder. Delphi 7 doesn't know any better; it calls `LoadLibrary` just like everything else, and that searches the system path.

Follow the Delphi example and give your packages **version-specific suffixes** reflecting what version of Delphi they're for. You should be able to configure that in the project options, or else you can just have version-specific project files that already have the version suffixes in their names. That way, even if the Delphi XE version of the package is visible on the path, it won't have the right name, so Delphi 7 won't try to load it.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I only tried (few weeks ago) to see if one of my packages compiles in Delphi XE... it looks like it compiled - he he. I didn't really intended to use XE for real, until yesterday. It didn't crossed my mind that XE will do that to D7. Otherwise, of course I intend to use version suffixes.